# How to resolve undefined:index and following errors in PHPmailer?

Tags: php, web, phpmailer

so i am trying to create a form on my website where client will enquire about the product. he will fill out a form and the contents of form will be sent to my email address using PHPMailer. but there is constant error showing about undefined: index email and undefined : index name also there is SMTP error too.
Error is Like This:

```
  Notice: Undefined variable: errors in C:\xampp\htdocs\event.php on line 13

  Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\event.php on line 34

  Notice: Undefined index: orgname in C:\xampp\htdocs\event.php on line 39
  Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. 
  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Here is my PHP Script

```
   if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||

  empty($_POST['email']) ||

  empty($_POST['message']))

 {

   $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";

 }



    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    require 'credentials.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

     //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                


    $mail->isSMTP();                                

    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                

     $mail->Username = EMAIL;                
     $mail->Password = PASS;                           
     $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           

    $mail->Port = 587;                                    


     $mail->setFrom($_POST['email']);

     $mail->addAddress(EMAIL, 'Nutriberry Client');    

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                 
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['orgname'];
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail 
          clients';

     if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';

 }
}
 ?>
```

and this is MY HTML FORM CODE:
Actually there are more fields in forms then I defined in  PHP script but i will do that myself, right now I am only worried about the error

```
<form method="POST" action="event.php" role="form">


    <div class="panel-body ">

        <label for="inputName " class="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 ">Requirement </label>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 ">
            <div class="fav_show_wrapper ">
                <select id="requirement " name="department">
                    <option value="Corporate Events ">Corporate Events</option>
                    <option value="Cafeteria Services ">Cafeteria Services</option>
                    <option value="Other ">Other</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>


        <label for="inputName " class="control-label col-lg-4 col-sm-4 "></label>
        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 " style="width: 50em">
            <div>
                <label>No. of Pax : </label> <select name="quantity" style="margin-left: 54px;margin-top:0.7em">
                        <option value="25-50 ">25 – 50</option>
                        <option value="51-100 ">51 – 100</option>
                        <option value="101-200 ">101 – 200</option>
                        <option value="Above 201 ">Above 201</option>
                        <option value="Other ">Other</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>



        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 " style="width: 80%;margin-top:0.7em">
            <label>Name of organisation:</label> <input type="text " class="form-control " id="orgname " name="orgname " placeholder="Name of organisation ">
        </div>



        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 " style="width: 80%">
            <label>Contact person:</label> <input type="text " class="form-control " id="name " name="name " placeholder="Name ">
        </div>



        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 " style="width: 80%">
            <label>Contact No.</label><input type="text " class="form-control " id="phone " name="phone " placeholder="Contact Number ">
        </div>



        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 " style="width: 80%">
            <label> Email Id</label> <input type="email " class="form-control " id="email " name="email " placeholder="Email ">
        </div>



        <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-8 " style="width: 80%">
            <label>Message</label> <textarea id="message " style="width: 100%; resize: none "></textarea>
        </div>



        <!-- <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 "></div> -->
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 " style="width: 80%">
            <div class="g-recaptcha " data-sitekey="6LcOFSITAAAAAMS2wYcWaOsSnMJYAISTW5K_nZeV "></div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-4 ">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary " style="margin-top: 1.5em;">Send</button>
        </div>


    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: first change $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required"; to $errors = "\n Error: all fields are required"; (without fullstop). second change your name and id tags, without space at the end, you set name to "email " and check $_POST['email']

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP issues.

All of these will attempt to access named keys in the `$_POST` variable, and will throw undefined index errors if they do not exist:

```
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||

  empty($_POST['email']) ||

  empty($_POST['message']))
```

Do this instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])  ||

  isset($_POST['email']) ||

  isset($_POST['message']))
```

`isset` is a PHP language construct, not a function (though it looks like one), and will not trigger errors. It has a dual function: the array element must be defined, and it must also not be `null` if it is to return true.

Here you're appending to a variable that doesn't exist yet:

```
$errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
```

Fix this by declaring it earlier in your script:

```
$errors = '';
```